# Package design: How to prevent R from loading sp package unnecessarily?

Tags: r, package, r-sp

I've made a package that exports spatial polygons objects. When using such objects, R automatically loads the `sp` package. Due to lazy loading of data, I was hoping that as long as the user does not use these spatial polygons objects, the `sp` package would not be loaded yet.

**What I want**

That the `sp` package is not loaded until the user uses / loads one of the spatial polygons objects in my package.

**What actually happens**

When I attach my package with `library(myPackage)`, it does indeed not load `sp`. However, all functions and objects in my package start with `mir_`, and as soon as I type `mir_` into my console, R loads `sp`. (I don't even need to execute any code, or even select any function or object. Just typing `mir_` is enough.)

**My questions**

- Why does R load `sp` even though I haven't used a spatial polygons object?
- Is it possible to solve this issue, so that `sp` is only loaded when a spatial polygons object is used / loaded?

**Extra info**

I'm using `LazyData: true` in my DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: Is that the console in Rgui or RStudio or a terminal? Because I suspect this results from RStudio's code completion feature.

Comment: It's in RStudio.

Comment: Please also test this in Rgui and report the result.

Comment: Have you tried putting all `sp` objects in the `data` directory?  Those won't be loaded until a user calls the `data()` function.  If they are just in the regular package namespace, they'll be loaded as soon as they are examined.  If they have have a class from `sp`, that forces `sp` to load too.

Comment: @user2554330 "Those won't be loaded until a user calls the data() function." That's not correct with `LazyData: true`.

Comment: @Roland is right.  So maybe use `LazyData: false`?

Comment: all `sp` objects are already in the `data` directory. Setting `LazyData: false` does solve the problem, but it creates another. Most of the data in the data folder should be accessible to users and package functions. Is there a way to combine `LazyData: true` for most objects with `LazyData: false` for the `sp` objects?

Comment: I've encountered this as well, `sp` is automatically loaded whenever an `sp*` object is detected in the environment. My workaround has just been to store the `sp` object information in lists etc. and then convert them to `sp` when needed, but that may or not may work for your scenario.